# SQL Server - Get all persons that turned 25 years old in a selected year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with 3 fields:

- fullname (Nvarchar(100))
- account (Nvarchar(50))
- birthdate (DateTime)

What I need is to create a query where I get all the persons that had their 25th birthday in a selected year.

> For example, to know all the persons that had their 25th birthday in the year 2003.

Right now I have this:

```
DECLARE @dynamicdate DATETIME
SET @dynamicdate = CONVERT(datetime, '20131231')

SELECT *
FROM persons p
WHERE
(year(@dynamicdate-p.birthdate)-1900)=25
```

But I know its totally wrong and It's should be very simple, any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do your best to avoid doing calculations or functions on columns used in a `WHERE` clause. instead, change the expression so the column is by itself one one side of the conditional expression, like below:

```
DECLARE @BirthYear int = 2003 - 25;

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Persons P
WHERE
   P.BirthDate >= DateAdd(year, @BirthYear - 2000, '20000101')
   AND P.BirthDate < DateAdd(year, @BirthYear - 2000, '20010101')
;
```

Please pay special attention to the inequality operators I used, `>=` and `<`. The best practice for date handling in SQL is to use an *inclusive* start (greater than or equal to) and an *exclusive* end (less than, but not equal to). This makes it possible to change the precision of the underlying column, for example to `datetime2(7)`, without having to change your code. It also makes it possible to join ranges contiguously with an equijoin (`Prior.ToDate = Next.FromDate`) and calculate range intersection correctly (`Range1.FromDate < Range2.ToDate AND Range2.FromDate < Range1.ToDate`).

If you cannot avoid having an expression on one column or another, put the expression on the column that has no indexes (leaving the column that does have an index by itself). Or, barring that (and this takes a bit of experience to know how to implement), put the expression on the side that in the query plan is earlier in the plan or affects the fewest rows.

Adding indexes, filtered indexes, and calculated persisted columns can all help with performance of often-repeated queries against date columns. But a warning: adding indexes can worsen performance, too.

Comment: Please see my update stressing the importance of using the right inequality operators in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply be able to query the year part of the date in question, as you just want to know if the persons 25th birthday fell into that year.

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT

SET @Year = 2003

SELECT *
FROM Persons P
WHERE ((@Year - DATEPART(yy, birthdate)) = 25)
```

This SQLFiddle Demonstrates http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b040c/2

Keep in mind this is not optimised, but I wouldn't bother doing optimisation until you have actually measured performance and determined that this particular query is a problem. I would focus on the simplest, easiest to read solution first.

Comment: I recommend you research how to make your where conditions "sargable".

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I hadn't run across the term "sargable" before. I would still prescribe the simplest solution first (not necessarily my solution), followed by performance testing to determine where the actual bottlenecks lie. Then the developer could apply any optimisations as necessary, except they will be targeted at the most appropriate place. I don't feel we know enough about the database or its contents to prescribe anything more than the most basic advice at this stage.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the normal adages about premature optimization don't apply here. It is the most BASIC best practice to make SQL query conditions sargable, without applying expressions to columns needlessly. Furthermore, there is nothing complicated about thinking of dates as ranges instead of using functions--you're just not used to it. You're espousing a *classic* pitfall that experienced developers first diving into SQL often do. Head over to http://dba.stackexchange.com and ask if sargability is something you should do after identifying a performance problem or before, and you'll see...

Answer (score 0):

you can use datepart for passing values(Can pass date too)
select * from Person where (datepart(year,'2007-12-31') - datepart(year,birthdate) ) = 25

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all birthdates are date only, (with no time portion), as they should be). then all you need is to Use this where clause:

```
where birthdate between 
     dateadd(year, @year-1925, 0) And
     dateAdd(day, -1, dateadd(year, @year-1924, 0))
```